# How to render a new message without re-rendering previous messages in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to add a new message from the form.js component into the message array which is in App.js, and mapping over through it to render that message.

But each time I add a new message all other messages in the array also get re-render, ***these previous messages should be on UI but they should not re-render***, Due to these, it creates a performance issue as if I want to add the 100th message then all other 99 messages also get re-render with the 100th message.

undesired output photo:-

[As you can see the console image I mapped over through the messageArr array to render message 4 but all other messages 1, 2, 3 also getting re-render with message 4. *I want other messages on UI but they should not get re-render* with the current message which is message 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHqTe.jpg)

What should I do to show previous messages with the current message without getting re-render?

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
const [messageArr, setMessageArr] = useState([]);

const addMessage = (messageText) => {
    setMessageArr([...messageArr, messageText]);
};

return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {messageArr.map(({ id, message }) => (
                <div key={id}>{message}</div>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <Form addMessage={addMessage} />
    </div>
);};
```

**Form.js**

```
const Form = ({ addMessage }) => {
const [messageText, setMessageText] = useState('');

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newMessage = {
        id: v4(),
        message: messageText
    } 
    addMessage(newMessage);
    setMessageText('');
};

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
            type='text'
            value={messageText}
            onChange={(e) => setMessageText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Add message</button>
    </form>
);}
```

Comment: It is unlikely React is the bottleneck here. It is far more likely the `v4()` function being called 100 times in a loop is the the source of performance problems. Change the `id` from calling `v4()` to a static value to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Having the `useEffect` function after you change the array is bound to log all the messages (since the `messageArr` changed). One thing you can try is to remove the dependency of messageArr.

Comment: The guide to StackOverflow is not to attach the error log as an image. Can you edit the log in text format? [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing you can do.

Make a new component for a single message and put these line in that component

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Message extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.message}</div>;
  }
}

export default Message;
```

Then in your main file you can change your return to

```
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {messageArr.map(({ id, message }) => (
                <Message key={id} message={message} />
            ))}
        </ul>
        <Form addMessage={addMessage} />
    </div>
)
```

Now since Message is a pure component, it will not rerender until its props is changed. So your old messages will not be rerendered again and only new message will render.

Comment: So can these solution work for functional components or I just need to use class-based approach?

Comment: Thanks Himanshu bhai using PureComponent it got solved